# Wait for a function to complete (axios call) before opening v-dialog

Tags: javascript, vue.js, asynchronous, axios, vuetify.js

Currently, when a button is clicked, an axios call will retrieve some information about a particular product and open, **AT THE SAME TIME**, a `v-dialog` showing all the information about the product.

The behavior I would like would rather be that the `v-dialog` opens **ONLY AFTER** the axios call is completed. I know that async functions would be usefull here, but the fact that the same button call the `axios` function AND opens the `v-dialog` is what's confusing me here.

Here's my code in template:

```
<v-dialog v-model="productInfoDialog" max-width="600px" :retain-focus="false">
                <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                  <v-btn color="primary" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" v-on:click="getProductInfo(row.item.id)">View Product</v-btn>
                </template>
                ...dialog content
              </v-dialog>
```

In script:

```
closeDialog() {
      this.productInfoDialog = false;
},
getProductInfo(id) {
      var url = this.$store.getters.URLs.Product.url;
      axios.get(url, {
      params: this.getProductParams(id),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //product info assignment
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response);
      })
},
```

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If got what you want just do it.

```
closeDialog() {
      this.productInfoDialog = false;
},
getProductInfo(id) {
      var url = this.$store.getters.URLs.Product.url;
      axios.get(url, {
      params: this.getProductParams(id),
      })
      .then((response) => {
        //here the request is completed
        //so you can open your dialog now
        this.productInfoDialog = true;
        this.productInfo.id = id;
        this.productInfo.img_url = response.data.data[0].img_url;
        this.productInfo.ecommerceUrl = response.data.data[0].url_en;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        this.productInfo.id= '';
        this.productInfo.img_url = '';
        this.productInfo.ecommerceUrl = '';
        console.log(error.response);
      })
}
```